# Use of "new do" in Rails 3 Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm working with a Rails 3 Routes file and the resource mapping looks like this:

```
resources :projects do
    new do
      post :add_test_phase
      post :add_client
      post :refresh_form
    end
```

I've read the Routes Guide for Rails 3 but find no mention of this. I know what "member" or "collection" add but am stumped by this new tag. Does it mean perform the mentioned posts when a new project is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just like the `post do` block does. It's just for creating a bunch of `new` routes. Your above example would give you `add_test_phase_new_project_path` mapped to `projects#add_test_phase`, `add_client_new_project_path` mapped to `projects#add_client`, `refresh_form_new_project_path` mapped to `projects#refresh_form`. The urls would be `/projects/new/add_test_phase`, `/projects/new/add_client` and `/projects/new/refresh_form`. Although, honestly, I don't really see a good use case for this.

Comment: Not quite. The member urls and named helpers would be a tad different, but the theory is the same.